# Choosing from movies, combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There are, 11 action movies, 9 romantic movies, and 5 thrillers. How many possibities are there to arrange this movies such that all 9 romantic movies stay together?

This should be the solution from my point of view
$9!*16!$, however the book says $9!*17!$ could this be a print error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a print error. Consider the 9 romantic movies as a single pack of movies. And consider the other movies as unitary pack of movies. So, the 9 romantic movies can be arranged in $9!$ ways. And the 11 action movies, 5 thrillers **AND** the 1 pack of 9 romantic movies can be arranged in $17!$ ways. Therefore the result is $9!17!$

Comment: Good point. By arranging in packets you build up packets, which builds extra possibilities for arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a print error. Indeed, $11+1+5=17\ne 16.$ In these elementary combinatorics book problems, we describe this approach of counting $9$ movies together as $9!$ different single movie series of $9$ movies, as they are arranged among themselves in $9!$ ways.

Don't forget to start by treating the $9$ as $1$ solitary being, and *then* by arranging them among themselves.